# gpt3 finetuning with fine-tunes.create argument is not working

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I want to finetune one openai model on my data, for that I gave this command (as per openai docs)

`openai api fine_tunes.create -t "abc_700_prepared_train.jsonl" -v "abc_700_prepared_valid.jsonl" --compute_classification_metrics --classification_n_classes 5`

But this error is coming

```
usage: openai api [-h]
                  {chat.completions.create,images.generate,images.edit,images.create_variation,audio.transcriptions.create,audio.translations.create,files.create,files.retrieve,files.delete,files.list,models.list,models.retrieve,models.delete,completions.create}
                  ...
openai api: error: argument {chat.completions.create,images.generate,images.edit,images.create_variation,audio.transcriptions.create,audio.translations.create,files.create,files.retrieve,files.delete,files.list,models.list,models.retrieve,models.delete,completions.create}: invalid choice: 'fine_tunes.create' (choose from 'chat.completions.create', 'images.generate', 'images.edit', 'images.create_variation', 'audio.transcriptions.create', 'audio.translations.create', 'files.create', 'files.retrieve', 'files.delete', 'files.list', 'models.list', 'models.retrieve', 'models.delete', 'completions.create')
```

Not sure why is this coming. As per openai docs [link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/legacy-fine-tuning), still this fine-tunes.create works.Can anyone help me on this?
`

I am expecting a finetuned ada model, after giving that command. A few months before I did the same way and it worked now it is not coming.

[refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTmiF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you execute command below for these few months?

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

Downgrading will be a solution. 0.28.1 is the version provided in the latter half of September, 2023.

```
pip install openai==0.28.1
```

After downgrading, `openai api fine_tunes.create` will work.

However, you may encounter [another error](https://community.openai.com/t/i-have-free-credits-but-can-no-longer-fine-tuning/245451).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and even after downgrading to openai==0.28.1.
I got another error saying you need to set the API key, but When I set the API_key, the error still says you need to set the API key and does not recognize the key.

Answer (score 0):

the installation was a success but i recieved this error "Error: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = ', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = '. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details.

"